# How can I make fonts in the top panel smaller?

Tags: fonts, appmenu

I can use Ubuntu Tweak to change font size on the background but I can't change this:

[image: pic]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal with and use this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences titlebar-font 'Ubuntu Bold 9'
```

It will change the font to Ubuntu bold with size 9.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open System Settings, for example by searching for it in the Dash:
[image: System Settings]
Open the options for Universal Access:
[image: Universal Access]
Here you can choose between four different text sizes:
[image: Text size]

Comment: As of 2023, I no longer see the Text size choices.  Only a slider that says make larger.